# Using multiple toolsets in one VS project - are there risks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In some of my projects, I need to support different versions of VC++, currently 2010, 2012 and 2015. At some point, 2017 will be added and support for 2010 will probably be dropped.

We currently maintain completely separate projects and solutions for the different VC++ versions. This has proven to work reliably but of course there are some drawbacks:

- Changes like adding or renaming a source file have to be made in all projects.
- We have to work with different versions of the IDE. (Not neccessarily, but when opening a project with a later IDE version there is the risk of accidentally converting it.)

I have suggested to work with a single project with different configurations that use different toolsets instead.

Two developers don't like this idea because they have tried this in the past and experienced certain issues. Unfortunately they do not remember exactly what these issues were. But as a result, the manager decided to stick with using multiple projects for now.

What are the risks or potential drawbacks of using multiple toolsets in one VC++ project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the risks or potential drawbacks of using multiple toolsets in one VC++ project?

I don't see any risks, and it's of course better just to manage this in the Configuration Manager and the specifically associated Project Properties within a single Solution.

There's no need to use different IDE Versions to achieve this properly.